# sql server query - pivot after n iteration

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 Columns:

```
'Employee'               'ReportsTo'
1                            
2                            1
3                            1
4                            2
5                            2
6                            3
7                            3
8                            4
9                            4
10                           5
```

I would like to return like this:

```
'Employee' 'Reporting Officer'
1           2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
2           4,5,8,9,10
3           6,7
4           8,9
5           10
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: are u sure for this row `2  -->    4,5,8,9,10` and not `2  --->    4,5` ? and if yes why u choosed 8,9,10

Comment: This isn't pivoting. It's an hierarchical query.

Answer (score 3):

This will work with your example table but not with tables like this (would need a more complex query):

```
Employee  ReportsTo
--------  ---------
12        13
13        12
```

And it is not called "pivot after n iteration".

```
with cte as (
  SELECT 1 Employee,0 ReportsTo UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,1  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6,3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7,3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8,4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9,4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 10,5
),

cte2 as (
  SELECT ReportsTo e,Employee ro FROM cte
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.e,b.Employee FROM cte2 a JOIN cte b ON a.ro = b.ReportsTo
)

SELECT
  Employee,
  ISNULL(LEFT(ro,LEN(ro)-1),'') as "Reporting Officer"
FROM (
  SELECT
    Employee,
    REPLACE(REPLACE((
      SELECT ro FROM cte2 x WHERE x.e=cte.Employee ORDER BY 1 FOR XML PATH('')
    ),'<ro>',''),'</ro>',',') ro
  FROM cte
) a
```

[sqlfidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8416)

Comment: thanks for the reply and sorry for the topic as I was not getting appropriate line to describe my problem. But my issue is that the tables has N numbers of combination. I would appreciate if you give a solution using a table. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is you mean "N numbers of combination" ? please give an example